# Using Cumulative Algorithm to Concatenate Strings of User Input

Tags: java, string, object, output, concatenation

I'm attempting to write a program that will ask a user how many pre-requisites a particular class has, ask for the name of each pre-requisite, and then output a list of the pre-requisites in a single line.

My program is running without returning any errors; however, when it outputs the list of the pre-requisites, it only repeats the last one entered by the user instead of listing all of the pre-requisites entered.  I believe that this is because the value of the object is changing every time the user enters a new pre-requisite; however, I cannot figure out how to get it to save each value and concatenate them together for the output.

The following code is what I'm using to collect the pre-requisites from the user

```
 public static void getPrereqs() { 
 System.out.print("How many pre-requisites does the course have? ");
 numPrereqs = console.nextInt();

 console.nextLine();

 for (int i = 1; i <= numPrereqs; i++) {
     System.out.print("List Pre-requisite #" + i + "? ");
     listPrereq = console.nextLine();
  }//Close for loop
}//Close getPrereqs method
```

and this is the code I'm using to output the list (also includes recalling some other pieces of information but those are outputting correctly)

```
  public static void printToScreen () {
  System.out.println(courseCode + ": " + courseName);
  System.out.print("Pre-requisites: ");
  for (int i = 1; i <= numPrereqs; i++) {
     System.out.print(listPrereq + ", ");
  }//Close for loop
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Total number of seats = " + TOTAL_SEATS);
  System.out.println("Number of students currently registered = " + studentsReg);

  openSeats = calcAvail(studentsReg);

  System.out.println("Number of seats available = " + openSeats);
  if (openSeats >= 5) {
     System.out.println ("There are a number of seats available.");
  }//Close if loop
  else {
     if (openSeats <= 0) {
        System.out.println ("No seats remaining.");
     }//Close if loop
     else {
           System.out.println ("Seats are almost gone!");
     }//Close else
  }//Close else statement
}//Close printToScreen method
```

I have seen some threads discussing array lists; however, I am very unfamiliar with what this is and not comfortable using one at this time.  Is there a way to get the results I'm looking for using a cumulative algorithm?

Comment: What kind of variable is   listPrereqs?It’s data type I mean

Comment: The data type for listPrereq is String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently overwrite the String variable `listPrereq` each iteration.  You need to store into an array (preferred), or concatenate as one large String.

If you do not like Lists, then an array should be fine.

Instead of declaring `listPrereq` as a `String`, instead declare as an array:

```
String[] listPrereq;
```

Then you need to create it large enough to store each prerequisite:

```
numPrereqs = console.nextInt();     
listPrereq = new String[numPrereqs];
```

Then store the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numPrereqs; i++) {
    System.out.print("List Pre-requisite #" + (i+1) + "? ");
    listPrereq[i] = console.nextLine();
} // Close for loop
```

Then to print:

```
System.out.print("Pre-requisites: ");
for (int i = 0; i < numPrereqs; i++) {
    System.out.print(listPrereq[i]);
    if (i != numPrereqs - 1)
        System.out.println(",");
}//Close for loop
```

You could concatenate together a large string instead of using arrays (is this your preference?), but you lose the ability then to easily refer to each prerequisite individually afterwards.

**EDIT:  How to create a large String**

```
String listPrereq = "";

for (int i = 0; i < numPrereqs; i++) {
    System.out.print("List Pre-requisite #" + (i+1) + "? ");
    listPrereq += console.nextLine();
    if (i != numPrereqs - 1)
        listPrereq += ",";
} // Close for loop

// To print:
System.out.println(listPrereq);
```

Comment: Although, it looks like an array is working, it is my preference to concatenate as one large string, if that's possible.  Can you offer advice as to how to go about doing the latter without losing each iteration?

Comment: Please review the edited answer.  This builds one large string.

Comment: I used both suggested methods and found that both work! I need to do quite a bit more research on arrays before I feel comfortable to incorporating them myself.  Thank you for your patience and thorough breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class CourseDetails {

    private static Scanner console;

    public static void getPrereqs() {
        console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numPrereqs;
        String listPrereq = "";
        System.out.print("How many pre-requisites does the course have? ");
        numPrereqs = console.nextInt();

        console.nextLine();

        for (int i = 1; i <= numPrereqs; i++) {
            System.out.print("List Pre-requisite #" + i + "? ");
            listPrereq = listPrereq + i + " " + console.nextLine();
            listPrereq = listPrereq + "\n";
        } // Close for loop
        System.out.println("Pre-requisites: ");
        System.out.println(listPrereq);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getPrereqs();
    }

}
```

Second Way:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CourseDetailsA {

    private static Scanner console;

    public static void getPrereqs() {

        console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numPrereqs;
        int j = 1;
        String[] listPrereq;
        System.out.print("How many pre-requisites does the course have? ");
        numPrereqs = console.nextInt();
        listPrereq = new String[numPrereqs];
        console.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i <= numPrereqs - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print("List Pre-requisite #" + j + "? ");
            listPrereq[i] = j + " " + console.nextLine() + "\n";
            j++;
        } // Close for loop

        System.out.println("Pre-requisites: ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= numPrereqs - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(listPrereq[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getPrereqs();
    }
}
```